# What are the black tubes protruding from my basement slab?

Tags: basement, floor

My house in Canada is 14 years old . From original construction, rising up out of the concrete basement floor are 18"  black tubes about 3/4 inch O.D. in three different locations . What are they for ?  Can I cut them off at floor level and seal them off ?  Any info is greatly appreciated .
.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Concrete floor? I'd bet PEX for in-floor heating (cheap/easy to add when pouring in case you might want it later, hard to add later) so I would not rush to chop it off. Could also be conduit.

Comment: Conduit would not be black. I'd say it is in floor hot water heating, either abandoned earlier or installed for future consideration. If originally installed and then it leaked, it's virtually impossible to fix so it may have been abandoned.

Comment: The tubes are not PEX . some pliable black plastic . I will try to find how to attach pic's .  Any tips on how to add pic's ?

Comment: I put a pic beside my name / profile .

Comment: @Rob - You should put your picture directly into the question. While you are in the editing mode of your question there is an ICON that is a box with what looks like a picture of two mountain peaks and a sun in the corner. Click that and it will guide you through inserting a proper picture in your question.

Comment: If it were (a little more recent and) in the US, and the color orange: hydronic floor heat. Except that they're in three different locations... how would you hook the spool valve up? A hydronic loop would need at least two in any given location. Possibly they're gas lines, water supplies,... condensate/radiator drains. Whatever they are or were, obviously do nothing now, or never did. - Use compressed air or a vacuum to find the other end.... where's number 4, or the other end of those three?

Comment: My guess is that they are irrigation hose used as underground conduit for future network/coax cables. Two of those hoses are probably the two ends of the same pipe, and the 3rd one connects with a 4th one hidden in a wall or somewhere you can't see it.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? I'd assume they were put there for a reason and not lop them off until I'm sure what it was, and that it's no longer valid.

Comment: If you have an air compressor, you could try blowing air into each of the tubes and seeing if they're all open and connected to each other in some way, or sealed up?  If you only had the one next to your incoming water supply I might have guessed a pipe coming from a decommissioned well, but that seems unlikely.  Any chance you could find out who the builder of your house was, and ask them?  Or if you live in a subdivision all built by the same builder, ask your neighbors if they have any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

We use it for water softener and humidifier drains.  It is a a lot cleaner than tie wrapping them to the floor drain screen like the gas furnace and air conditioner.

Comment: Wouldn't that require that there be a trap somewhere below?

Answer (score 0):

It’s an auxiliary drain line that would connect back into your primary floor drain system from the looks of it. Also acts as a breather preventing air lock from occuring. I wouldn't recommend removing it or sealing it.

Comment: Too small to be a drain...it would clog up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).